# comma usage question: a New Yorker example

Tags: grammar, punctuation, word-usage

> Spoon had a scheduled appearance the next day on “The Late Show with Stephen Colbert,” and another after that at the Hammerstein Ballroom.

I came upon this sentence in The New Yorker, and based on the way a friend had explained the punctuation of compound predicates, I thought the magazine had violated its house style by placing a comma before a conjunction that is followed by a compound predicate. When I looked up compound predicate, I realized that there is no compound predicate in the sentence because there aren't any verbs in the second part of the sentence to share a subject with the verb in the sentence's main clause.

My question: is there guidance or a relevant rule (in, for instance, the Chicago Manual of Style or another style guide—and in asking this, I am asking a question which can be answered factually with reference to sources, rather than a question based on opinion) concerning the comma before "and" in the New Yorker example sentence? Do any style guides consider the comma obligatory there? Is it always considered optional?

I know the convention about putting a comma before a conjunction that separates two independent clauses and know the convention about not placing a comma before a conjunction when the conjunction separates a verb from its subject in a compound predicate, but I don't know what rules, if any, apply to the comma in the example sentence. I'd be thankful for any information.

Comment: Right on your analysis, but the comma is yours for the taking whenever you feel it helps clarity. You'd leave it out for a shorter pair: *The next day on “The Late Show with Stephen Colbert” and the Hammerstein Ballroom*.

Comment: The "conventions" you mention are bogus; commas are aural. If you hear them, you put them in. They are not occasioned by  preceding or following certain (types of) words.

Comment: @JohnLawler Have you -seen- the style guides of these publications? They may well be conventions, and also bogus, but they are also enforced by those publications, and trillions (I did the calculation) of person-years of secondary school education have been spent to get people to learn some close approximation of them.

Comment: @Mitch And how well has that worked out?

Comment: Not well if you violate their style.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not a prescriptivist, and I'm not broadly in favor of arbitrary usage rules. That said, one is sometimes called upon to follow them. I want to be able to, when it's required of me. These rules are of interest in their own right too: their genealogy illustrates something of the history of language usage norms, and being aware of rules—as arbitrary as they are—can help one attend to aspects of syntax that are otherwise easily overlooked. And the examples have something of the pleasure of a chess problem—not that I've experienced this purported pleasure, vis-a-vis chess problems.

Comment: It's fortuitous that your example clearly offsets with both the inverted commas, and the line-break here. The comma would be an aid to parsing, and is an aid to breathing when reading aloud,  such a lengthy sentence.

Comment: The recent edit argues that as it's now a request for a fact-based response, it's not opinion-based – but it's still asking for a "rule", when no such rule exists. Twisting the question so that reference to style guides is required doesn't make this on-topic: it's still as off-topic as me asking what the rule is about the cedilla in *façade*. Answer: as with punctuation, there *is* no rule – you'll just have to check with your intended publisher or read your institution or company's preferred style guide or make a judgement about your intended audience. I'm voting to keep the question closed.

Comment: Because I ask if there is a rule, and the answer could be, as you argue, “no,” I don’t see why question would be considered opinion-based. And there are rules to punctuation: see my placement of the comma inside of quotation marks, rather than outside. This follows the rule in American usage. Of course the rule is arbitrary. All rules grammar and usage rules are arbitrary. Even rules from modern linguistics that considers normal speech of any native speaker grammatical are arbitrary, or contingent, given that the relevant conceptual framework could be otherwise. There’s no “outside.”

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a rule. When a conjunction coordinates two conjuncts, then the author may make the second nonrestrictive by surrounding it (along with the preceding conjunction) with paired punctuation (dashes, parentheses, or commas). I've recently given examples on this site (["Why, and how" VS "Why and how"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585676/why-and-how-vs-why-and-how/585678)):

> Why, and how, does the pH level affect the resulting popping boba?
> Why (and how) does the pH level affect the resulting popping boba?
> Why--and how--does the pH level affect the resulting popping boba?

. . . and on ELL (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314698/comma-before-and-also/314706):

> People say that the Earth has four (or sometimes five) oceans.
> Oregon--but not Idaho--is on the Pacific Ocean.
> My friend Alice, and her dog Bucky, will arrive tomorrow.

If you're from the "minimalist" school of punctuation, then you should only include this punctuation when the second element is really nonrestrictive (or parenthetical). (See what I did there?) In fact, many guides consider inclusion of such punctuation in other situations to be an error. (E.g., see the first example at https://owl.excelsior.edu/grammar-essentials/common-errors/common-errors-unnecessary-comma/ .) Because there doesn't seem to be any need in your sentence for the second conjunct to be nonrestrictive, I would omit the comma:

> Spoon had a scheduled appearance the next day on “The Late Show with Stephen Colbert” and another after that at the Hammerstein Ballroom.

However, keep in mind that not everyone subscribes to the "minimalist" school, and people have a wide variety of opinions about commas. (See [John Lawler's comment above](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/588744/comma-usage-question-a-new-yorker-example#comment1476705_588744), for example.)

Comment: It's also worth noting that *New Yorker* is against the minimalist school. See, e.g., ["In Defense of Nutty Commas"](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/in-defense-of-nutty-commas).

Comment: If you are concerned with rules of punctuation I’d do something about your representation of em dashes. The necessity for double hyphens on the web went out last century.

Comment: @David Yes, actual dashes would work better here. Sometimes I use double hyphens for convenience (it's easier than inserting the em-dash character). I also often use monospaced fonts, where double hyphens generally work better than actual dashes.

Comment: @David There are many sites on the web (Goodreads, for example) where em dashes are generally unavailable unless you type in the HTML. Same with boldface and italic. Double hyphens are sufficient.

Comment: @Zan700 — I am not able to test Goodreads, but I very much doubt what you say because your comment shows you do not understand the difference between character representation and text styling. The former (but not the latter) involves various international standards for representing characters as binary bytes and interpretation depends on web browser capabilities, not the website. Nor do these standards involve HTML. You'd be pushed today to find a web browser that will not take this sort of thing: ボビン булавка תפירה ç č . You just need to learn how to type them. Easy on a Mac or iPhone.

Comment: @David If I should type in or copy Title=Trashlands  by Alison Stine &#8212; Blog Tour &#8211; Excerpt &amp;&nbsp;Interview"> and then publish, I will get  Trashlands by Alison Stine — Blog Tour – Excerpt & Interview. None of the usual shortcuts to an em dash or an en dash have ever worked for me on GR.  If I got desperate, I'd resort to the above, but as I mentioned, double hyphens are sufficient. Enlighten me on producing an em dash in GR directly from my keyboard.

Comment: @Zan700 — Where in GR? I opened a test account but have no idea where you are typing stuff. What do I do next? And what’s your keyboard — Mac, Win, iOS, Android?

Comment: @David Choose a book and review it. The space that opens for the review is where I most commonly type. Win 10.  I use every browser.

Comment: @Zan700 — I just published a review of a book called Anthracite by Cédric Gras under the name of Attila Hun. I used an em-dash from my Mac keyboard (option   + shift + hyphen ) and copied and pasted Švejk  from a Wikipedia page. I only use Windows under emulation, but apparently there are virtual keyboards you can use — https://www.theverge.com/22351023/windows-pc-special-characters-how-to

Comment: @David If you get the opportunity, see if you can do it on a Win keyboard. Yes, copying and pasting works fine, but in the heat of battle I stick with the double hyphen. Thanks for the effort. How did Attila like Anthracite?

Comment: @Zan700 — I’ll try over the weekend. Anthracite was reading for a monthly French literary group, where one tends to judge books on the basis of whether they were as bad as the last one. But “use it or lose it”.

Comment: @Zan700 — One way on Windows is to type "character" in the search field and it brings up something called the Character Map (similar to something on Mac). This has everything you could need, but for some unknown reason there is no index and the em dash is about three-quarters of the way down (see: https://windowslovers.com/type-an-em-dash/). Otherwise, if you have a numeric keypad, Alt 0151 is supposed to work.

Comment: @David I appreciate your quest for my em-dash, but my computer has no numeric keypad, and all the shortcuts I've seen require numeric keypads. In Word, I type double hyphens and without much further trouble it converts to an em-dash. In GR, Library Thing and other sites, I suppose I could use the Character Map, but that seems much more time-consuming than the lickety-split double hyphen. End Man, October 22

Comment: I see negligible difference between << Why, and how, does the pH level affect ... >> and << Why and how does the pH level affect ... >> I read the _and how_ as a parenthetical (from a syntactic aspect) off-settable by ellipses. brackets, dashes, commas, or (in this case; sometimes this would cause loss of clarity) zero punctuation at each end. Each chosen style adds differing degrees of dramatic-pause(-if-any) emphasis. But as for restriction/non-restriction? What is being identified (cf _the man[,]who was wearing a red hat_ – ditching the comma gives a defining/identifying RC)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that "parenthetical" might be a better word to use here. I often consider the terms somewhat interchangeable (for several reasons that wouldn't quite fit in a comment), but if you think it would be best I could go back and edit the answer.

Comment: But I'm saying that I'd not find the smooth-running 'Why and how does the pH level affect the resulting popping boba?' at all unacceptable. In this case, I'd prefer slight drama-enhancing, giving-time-for-thought, pauses (thus offsetting commas), but this is a style issue. I see no change in meaning, only delivery / effectiveness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that there's some effect on meaning: In that sentence, the paired punctuation suggests that the contained text is not part of the speakers' main thrust but somewhat of an aside or less important element. If the author wanted "why" and "how" to have equal weight, then I'd definitely recommend omitting the commas.

Comment: Not in this case. 'Why' and 'how' are poles apart. The addition of more weighty punctuation than zero is pragmatic, ponderous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, but I think I'm missing something. In your previous comment you said that you "preferred" commas, but now you say that adding punctuation is "pragmatic, ponderous". I'm not quite following.

Comment: Yes, the default is pejorative. An adjective meaning 'makes one think about what's being said'. I thought pragmatic would point to the 'weight added' rather than 'clumsy' sense.